# css is not working in my web2py application

Tags: css, web2py

I am building a web2py application.

I use my own css file called style.css

I do know that the following code

```
{{response.files.append(URL('static','css/base.css'))}}
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
```

will link my css file to my application.

I use this for layout.html; which is used for every page of application.

Initially, I do not have problem with this...

Suddenly, at some point, my css is not updated...

Every css before the point, works fine.
Every css after the point, do not work at all.

In web2py editor, all css changes are updated. However, If if run it, the css is not updated... If I inspect the css code using chrome, the css is not updated and remain to previous css file..

for clarification, I give you example

initially I just have the following.

```
#title{
       font-size: 90px; 
}
```

then I change it to the following

```
#title{
      font-size:100px;
}
```

IN the web2py editor, the change is saved and set it to 100px. However, if i run the application and view css file using chrome inspect, it is still remained as 90px.

I thought the server may have some error, so I restarted. I still get error.

Another thing I can think of is the confit with bootstrap..

The following is the head part of layout.html

```
<head>
<title>NR</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {{response.files.append(URL('static','css/bootstrap.min.css'))}}
    {{response.files.append(URL('static','css/style.css'))}}
    {{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}

</head>
```

Actually, I do have a solution...
If I create css file with different name, and copy and paste all css work, it work!!
However, this takes extra work... create new css file and copy and paste.... It is not good way.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your web server is configured to set the HTTP response headers so the assets will be cached by the browser (in which case, they will not be re-sent on every request). If this is just a development issue, you can simply force your browser to reload all assets (e.g., by pressing CTRL-F5).

For a more general solution, see the documentation on [static asset management](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Static-asset-management).

Another option is to let web2py serve the static content itself, in which case, the assets will be re-requested with each page and web2py will return 304 responses if the assets have not changed since last sent.